# TestCafe Authentication results in a 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied.... error

Tags: authentication, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, access-denied

**Issue:**

I am trying to get TestCafe to open an internal website that triggers a windows authentication pop up on opening, but the TestCafe built in Authentication feature doesn't work for some weird reason and the website complains with "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

Note manually I can open the website with the same login credentials.

Also note the Authentication feature does work for other websites, and I am doing this at work, so there is a work proxy.

**The site that TestCafe is failing to open up:**

Is made up of a server name & port only & lives internally eg.

http://[ServerName]:[Port]

**The Code:**

Made up of 2 files....

The Test Script:

```
import {Selector} from 'testcafe';


fixture('My Test')
    .page('http://[ServerIP]:[Port]/')  // Also tried ('http://[ServerName]:[Port]')    
    .httpAuth({
        username: 'domain\name',
        password: 'password_here'

    })


test ('Opening this internal site', async t => {

    await t    

    .debug()

});
```

The Runner file:

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let testcafe           = null; 


createTestCafe('localhost', '8081')
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe = tc;
        const runner = testcafe.createRunner();


        return runner
            .src([
                'My_Test.js'                
             ])
            .browsers('chrome')
            .useProxy('webproxy01:8080', '[ServerIP]:[Port]') // I tried including the website that I want to test incase it needs to be ByPassed
            .run({
                skipJsErrors: true,                
                concurrency: 1
            })
    })
    .then(failedCount => {
        console.log(`Tests failed: ` + failedCount);
        testcafe.close();
    });
```

Just to add I've tried this too and it doesn't work either:

```
.httpAuth({
        username: 'name',
        password: 'password_here',
        domain: 'domain_here',
        workstation: 'computer_name'
    })
```

Many thanks!

Comment: It looks like you specify credentials in the wrong way. Try to debug what happens after TestCafe sends a response. Add a breakpoint inside the 'sendRequest' function in /node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/request-pipeline/index.js file and inspect the response.

Comment: Hi Mlosev, thanks for the reply, is there anything particular I should look at in the response as there is a lot data in there ?

Comment: Nothing particular. Review all properties of the response (and request) to find a clue on why your website does not allow access.